# Spring Batch , HSQLDB growing over the time

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, spring-batch, hsqldb

I am using spring batch to monitor `Rabbit MQ`. I was trying to do a stress stress by running the batch every second. It is running smoothly so far but the Used `Perm Generation space` is keep on growing. When the batch started it was `30 MB` now after `30 Hours` of running it is at `300 MB`. The biggest object occupying the memory is

```
org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLMemory 28619232
org.hsqldb.Database 96661000
```

This two object hold **32% of total memory**.

Can anyone please suggest how configure `HSQLDB` not hold information more than 5 mins old as we don't have any requirement of job to be restarted.

Comment: Use a real, external database for the job repository.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HSQLDB with default all-in-memory tables. All data is held in memory. This type of table allows very fast operation and is ideal for use-cases where the data does not grow beyond a certain limit.

You can add a task to delete the old rows periodically. This can be a TRIGGER declared on the table that grows, which deletes old rows according to their timestamp after a new row is inserted.

Alternatively, you can use CACHED tables, which hold the data mainly on disk. You can add `;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached` to the end of the JDBC connection URL. In this case the URL must indicate a file-based database, not an in-memory one.

So HSQLDB can act the same way as an external database if you want it to.